# gdal_translate syntax windows command line

Tags: gdal, windows, gdal-translate

I am trying to extract a band from a MODIS hdf file on windows with gdal_translate.

Here's my prompt:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff "HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:\"MOD13A2.A2009001.h17v08.005.2009020092120.hdf\":MODIS_Grid_16DAY_1km_VI:1km 16 days NDVI" NDVI.tif
```

However I get:

```
ERROR 4: `'HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:MOD11A2.A2009001.h17v07.005.2009014044746.hdf:MODIS
_Grid_8Day_1km_LST:LST_Day_1km'' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

GDALOpen failed - 4
`'HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:MOD11A2.A2009001.h17v07.005.2009014044746.hdf:MODIS_Grid_8Da
y_1km_LST:LST_Day_1km'' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
```

I imagine it's something to do with my syntax being a bit 'iffy' though it seems perfectly fine to me

Help much appreciated

Comment: Try using `\\\` for `\\`

Comment: As in:  ````gdal_translate -of GTiff `HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:\\`MOD13A2.A2009001.h17v08.005.2009020092120.hdf\\`:MODIS_Grid_16DAY_1km_VI:1km 16 days NDVI` NDVI.tif````. This doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 1):

No need to escape the double quotes. The following works (in Win XP):

```
gdal_translate "HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13A2.A2009001.h17v08.005.2009020092120.hdf":MODIS_Grid_16DAY_1km_VI:1km 16 days NDVI" NDVI.tif
```

Also note that `GTiff` is the default output format and doesn't need to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the `:` in the files name. It may be treated by the Windows Operating system as drive delimiter.

Comment: But those are in stored within the hdf file... eg `MODIS_Grid_16DAY_1km_VI:1km 16 days NDVI` is the subdataset name. Will `\:` work?

Comment: Have you tried only one quotation around all, and no backslashes? I'm not sure whether ecaping with backslashes works on the command line.